# Update select dropdown immediately when trigger event

Tags: angular

I have select box with dropdown list. This data comes from response So i want to update data whenever change data.

```
<mat-select placeholder="Kategorie auswählen" [(ngModel)]="categoryid" (selectionChange)="categorychanged(categoryid)">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let category of mainshoppinglistitems" [value]="category._id">
          {{category.dishType}}
     </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

So if i trigger event and try to change data from response. It is not updated when i click on select box.

```
getUpdateData() {
     this.cartservice.getShoppingListOnly().then(response => {
      this.mainshoppinglistitems = response['data'];
    });
}
```

How can i update DOM when change `mainshoppinglistitems`

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz reproduction of your issue ?

Comment: What you exactly want to implement. because in current situation you are trying to get list of drop-down that you currently selected from that list?

Comment: console array -> this.mainshoppinglistitems = response['data']; and see array is updated or not ?

Comment: I just tried your code and it's working as expected with an updated dropdown list.

Comment: My response not updating immediately that particular item. if i refresh its updating. something wrong with getting response.

Comment: I got it. The problem is i am using same method for uploading my file but getting response before uploading. So what i did, after getting event response, then i execute my getting updated list from DB. This works thank you for your suggestions.